# Evernote Web hook vs pulling

Tags: evernote

If a Webhook call fails for any reason will it be triggered again, how do I know that it failed?

Do I need to pull in any case to make sure I get all the notes?

If I am pulling am I restricted to 1 call every 15 minutes per account, or 1 call every 15 minutes globally and if I need to retrieve 2000 notes I need to make several calls, will that also be restricted per each chunk?

Answer (score 0):

When you're done processing the webhook, you should return a [status code of 200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to let the Evernote service know that you successfully received it. If it sends a webhook and does not get a 200 back, it should keep re-sending the webhook until it does, although there may be a limit to its number of retries, I'm not sure.

When you say "pull", I assume you mean to use the Evernote API to query the Evernote service. In that case, you're not limited to 1 call every 15 minutes - you can make many more calls than that. It's not unlimited, though; there is a [documented rate limit in place](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/rate_limits.php).